# Django Post shows with HTML tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-tinymce

I have created a small blog that includes django-tinymce in model.py file. After I write a text in the Admin console and publish it, the text is shown with HTML tags. Please see the example bellow:[image]

This is my model.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from tinymce.models import HTMLField


    class Post(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        text = models.TextField()
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        text = HTMLField()
    
        def publish(self):
            self.published_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

I can't find any reason why it is happening. I followed the documentation and should get a text without any tags.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use like this {{ text|safe }} in your template.